# grep all the lines in a file and write line to a file from the pattern matching point

Tags: text-processing, files, grep, vi

For example, a `temp.txt` file contains information like below:

```
adsf on line jhkjhvjdbvjvbvbdjkvn  
qerwtt on line fdgdgdgdd  
qwqertg on line safffasffaf  
wrt on line adaddsd
```

I want to grep for `on line` in all the lines of the file and write the remaining part of the lines to another file, i.e after the process on `temp.txt` file the new file should contain:

```
on line jhkjhvjdbvjvbvbdjkvn  
on line fdgdgdgdd  
on line safffasffaf  
on line adaddsd
```

How can I do that in linux terminal?

Comment: What do you want to happen with lines that do not contain `on line`?  How about lines that contain `on line` multiple times?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `-o` option of `grep` to select only the desired portion, in your case use pattern `on line .*` to select the portion starting from `on line` till the end of the line(s):

```
% grep -o 'on line .*' temp.txt >new.txt

% cat new.txt 
on line jhkjhvjdbvjvbvbdjkvn  
on line fdgdgdgdd  
on line safffasffaf  
on line adaddsd
```

Comment: for me this is what i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Given the `vi` tag on this question, and the fact that I've found that automated file editing with [POSIX-compliant `ex` commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) gets short shrift on this site compared to the plethora of advice on `sed`, `awk`, `grep` and even Perl, here is a POSIX-compliant `ex` command that will perform the desired filtering:

```
ex -sc 'g/.*\(on line\)/s//\1/ | .w!>>output
q!' input
```

Note the embedded newline in the command—this is necessary for full POSIX portability as there is no other definite way to end the `g`lobal command; however *most* implementations allow multiple `-c` commands, in which case the following one liner would work just the same:

```
ex -sc 'g/.*\(on line\)/s//\1/ | .w!>>output' -c 'q!' input
```

---

There is bit of regex magic and a lot of `ex`-command magic contained in this command, and since `ex` doesn't seem to be very widely known, I'll explain each part:

`-s` starts `ex` in silent mode, "in preparation for batch processing", so nothing gets output to your terminal.

`-c` means "Run the following command when the file is opened."  (`input` is the name of the file to open.)

The `ex` command itself is really two commands:

```
g/.*\(on line\)/s//\1/ | .w!>>output
q!
```

`g` is the "global" command and means, "Run the following commands (the rest of the line) on all lines of the file matching the specified regex."

The regex given is `.*\(on line\)`, which means 'Any characters any number of times, including 0, followed by "on line"'.  The parentheses are used to capture "on line" for backreferencing later.

In actual fact the `g` command itself could just as well be `g/on line/` and it would work the same.  However, the `s`ubstitute command I wrote uses *nothing* for its regex—`s//`—which means "reuse the last used regex".  Then the `s` command uses `\1` for the replacement text, meaning "on line" in this case.

The pipe symbol `|` in an `ex` command doesn't mean a pipe as it does in the shell.  Instead it is *usually* used to delimit separate `ex` commands, each to be run sequentially but independently.  However the `g`lobal command is an exception to this: in a global command, the vertical bar separates commands which are all *within* the global command—that is, such commands are only run *on the lines matching the regex* specified in the global command.

The command following the vertical bar is in this case a `w`rite command.  It's preceded by a dot `.` specifying "current line"; without this address specifier the write command will write the *entire* file, regardless of what is the current line.  (Since we're using the write command within a global command, if we were to omit the dot, the write command would write the entire file after *each* matching line had the substitution command performed on it!)

The `>>` means, "If the file already exists, append to it rather than giving an error."  Since we're writing to the file multiple times, this is necessary, otherwise we would only end up with the *last* line that was written to the output file.  The `!` preceding the `>>` means "If the file *doesn't* already exist, create the file and write to it rather than throwing an error."  (Without the `!` it's unspecified in POSIX whether this would happen or not.)  And of course `output` is the name of the file to write to.

Finally, of course, `q!` means "quit without saving changes to the current file."  We've made substitutions on many lines of the `input` file, but we don't want to save those changes, so we use `q!`.

---

There are some other approaches which are equivalent, for example the following:

```
ex -sc '%s/.*\(on line\)/\1/e | v//d
w output | q!' input
```

But this uses the `e` flag to the substitute command, which is not in POSIX.  (If this flag is omitted, the batch processing will stop on the occasion where the regex `.*\(on line\)` isn't found anywhere in the file.)

---

Of course, where `ex` *really* shines is in *in-place* file editing.  But it can certainly be used to filter a file out to another file, as illustrated above.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grep -o 'on line .*' temp.txt > out.txt
```

The `-o` parameter makes grep only output the matching part of the line, which is what you want.

Comment: How does it differ from the already provided answer?

Comment: It's the same, we both wrote it at the same time :P

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` doesn't support the `-o` option:

```
sed 's/^.*\(on line\)/\1/' temp.text > out.txt
```

Or if you only want the lines that contain `on line`:

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(on line\)/\1/p' temp.text > out.txt
```

Note that if there are several occurrences of `on line`, it prints the portion of the line that starts with the *rightmost* occurrence of it. For the leftmost occurrence:

```
sed '/on line/!d;s//\
&/;s/.*\n//' temp.text > out.txt
```

Comment: I suppose the OP didn't quite specify whether he wanted to include lines from the original file that *don't* contain "on line"...I read it that he doesn't want those lines (since he said "grep for it" which would exclude non-matching lines) but I guess you interpreted it differently.  You could add `-n` and the `p` flag (to the `s` command) to better approximate `grep -o`, though.